# Wireless Disabled on Boot

Tags: boot, wireless

On my Ubuntu 16.04 box, a MacBook Air 7,2, some recent update that I installed in the last few weeks have caused the WiFi to be disabled upon boot.  Network Manager says the network is enabled, but if I go to System Preferences and click on Network, [the "WiFi" view shows the wireless device switched off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRlLf.png) (the top-right button of the light-gray part of the window is switched to "off").

By clicking on that button the wireless becomes enabled and I can use it just fine, but it's really annoying to have to do this each time I boot.  Where should I look into to figure out what's causing this nuisance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this in the terminal:

```
nmcli radio all on
```

For more options read the manpage for nmcli.